# Exclude classes from code coverage in coveralls

Tags: .net, opencover, appveyor, coveralls

Currently I learn Appveyor and i use coveralls for .Net code coverage of mine source code. When i looked on the report i saw that i have a couple of classes (mostly models) which i cannot cover with unit test. I found one attribute `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]`  which is not working with Coveralls integration. I found in the documentation that i can include in `-filter`  ddls which i want to be covert, but it's will be paint full, because in reality the classes for excluding are less.

Is it possible somehow to exclude specific classes from code coverage ?

appveyor.yml 
`after_test: 
  - packages\OpenCover.4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe 
  -register:user 
  -filter:"+[**]*" 
  -target:"packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.1\tools\nunit3-console.exe" 
  -targetargs:"/domain:single test\PATH-TO-UNIT-TEST-DLL" 
  -output:coverage.xml`

Regards

Comment: Not sure how to exclude classes from code coverage in coveralls, but this appveyor.yml will not be parsed successfully. Please use single-line command. Good practice when you learning AppVeyor is to use UI and Export YAML menu.

Comment: @ilyaf - I believe you can use ^ at the end of the lines in appveyor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the section on [Understanding Filters](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/wiki/Usage#understanding-filters)

e.g. `-filter:"+[*]* -[MyModule]MyNamespace.MyClass"`